# Is IsDebuggerPresent() function a safe method to stop a process from being debugged?

Tags: c++, winapi

I want not to let my program debugged . I have a second thread that repeatedly checks whether a debugger is attached or not :

```
while(1){
    BOOL isDebugged = IsDebuggerPresent();
    if(isDebugged){
          //exit from my app
    }
    //and then check CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent()
}
```

I want to know whether this method is secure or not? Can someone debug my app even with this protection? Is there better way ?

**Edit :**
Actually I have a hardware security token. I want to protect my app from being copied . But I've heard that a simple true/false checking using the token will be broken by debugging the app

Comment: I can use my debugger to suspend your thread.

Comment: Looks like your superego consider your software to have no bugs! :-))

Comment: What will you do when the hacker uses Detours or similar technique to inject his own version of IsDebuggerPresent into the runtime? I can simply edit your binary's import table to for IsDebuggerPresent to load from my DLL.

Comment: I would rather know what it is that you are trying to protect in your code.  If we knew that, we can likely give you a better pointer on how to implement the security you are after.

Comment: @selbie -> Thank you. I have a hardware security token. I want to protect my app from being copied . But I've heard that a simple true/false checking using the token will be broken by debugging the app.

Comment: @saeed *anything* can be broken by debugging the app. That's kind of what a debugger does: letting you inspect and manipulate a running process.

Comment: Will this loop steal 1/(number of processors) of my CPU time or does IsDebuggerPresent wait for a system interrupt? Hmm if not you should add a sleep of at least 10 ms. Anyway, I will not buy your app but look for a GPL:ed alternative :-P

Comment: @user877329 : I'm not going to sell this app to users with rep lower than 1000 :P. I'm joking :D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There will always be ways to get around any protection you put in place, the only thing you can do is make it difficult enough that any attacker will get too frustrated and declare it is not worth his time to try and reverse engeneer your software. It is just a matter of **how much time/money is it worth it to you to keep that one extra person from trying**.

To answer if just checking `IsDebuggerPresent` safe? I have bypassed that exact security measure in software I have had to reverse engineer by decompiling the code with [OllyDbg](http://www.ollydbg.de/) finding any imports to the `IsDebuggerPresent` function and patching the exe to just return false instead, it took me about 15 minutes to get around the protection. Someone who is "Experienced" in reverse engineering likely could have done it in 5.

The only thing you can do is "Raise the bar" to keep your program from being reverse engineered, here are a few suggestions:

- Obfuscate your code
- Detect if common debugging software is currently running (Visual Studio, OllyDbg, IDA, ect...)
- Pay/higher a expert consultant to look over your code and make it harder to debug for people who do not have the source.

Some of these solutions (like detecting if a debugger is running) may piss off legitimate users who use debuggers for other software but are not trying to use it on your software, so you need to weigh the costs.

Comment: Not to mention that there are cases when running laws explicitly say that r.e. is legal, hence preventing it can be considered somewaht unfair (if not illegal)

Answer (score 12):

Anybody can see you using this function, it is trivially visible from Dumpbin.exe /imports. A simple api hook eliminates it.  So, no, this is completely not worth the trouble.  The only one that's going to be slowed-down by it is *you*, being defeated by your own counter-measure when you need to attach a debugger some day to solve a problem.

If you really care about this then just spend the money on an anti reverse-engineering software product.  Something like Armadillo, there are plenty.  They use more than one way to check for a debugger, techniques are a trading secret of course.  They'll also defeat disassembly attempts.

And don't overlook the real cost of this.  I personally have to deal with this kind of software in the product I work on every day.  Both licensing enforcement schemes for media codecs and DRM for video-on-demand downloads.  Calling them a PITA doesn't quite match the pain and suffering experienced by us having to deal with them.  Especially the anti-debugging techniques are painful, throwing uncatchable exceptions when trying to debug the app.  So this stuff just doesn't get debugged and is a never-ending source of bugs and breakage.  The more aggressive stuff just got removed first chance we got, with everybody contributing to the chances, completely defeating the intent.  A crashing bug in the DRM software completely diagnosed by me with specific recommendations to fix it took a year and a half to actually get fixed.  The DRM is particularly ineffective, I recently calculated that the cost of maintaining it can be amortized by giving everybody that downloads a movie a free copy with a five dollar gift certificate.  This just doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that the function is *perfect*. It always delivers an accurate answer and nothing an attacker can do will change that. Let's pretend that's the case.

Well, then. The attacker obviously has debugging privileges for your process, which means they can edit the process' memory. So they just change the instruction which normally calls that instruction, to call a dummy function which always returns false instead.

If I can attach a debugger to your process, then it means I have read and write permissions to your process' memory, and it means I can do whatever I please with it. There is nothing you can do about that.

If you want to avoid people attaching debuggers to your process, then you have to run it on a computer under your control, where the user can log in with an account with limited permissions. The OS decides whether a user is allowed to mess around with the memory of a process or not. If the OS decides that the user has that right, then the user has that right, and he is able to use it.

Answer (score 3):

I would personally recommend against using general anti-debugging features for the purposes of copy protection unless you have a really compelling and demonstrable reason for doing so.

On the one hand, you will gain very little in regards to actual copy protection (companies that spend big bucks on copy protection schemes, including anti-debugging tricks, routinely find their cracked software on torrent sites within hours of release.)

And on the other hand, you will be limiting the utility of your product. Most of the best software products are extensible, meaning users will create plugins for them or chain them with other software to be used in interesting ways outside of the vision of the original authors. These users being able to debug their work when doing this is critical, and that usually means they need a debugger attached to your process even if they are not trying to debug YOUR code.

Now I'm not saying copy protection is not worth pursuing, but there are many other methods available that don't prevent users from having a debugger attached. There are also other legitimate reasons for wanting to prevent debugging - such as protecting anti-cheat measures in online games, but you should make sure you have a really good reason for using it. For the most part, obfuscation and self-monitoring code is going to be your best bet, and anybody that can break that will find it pretty easy to break most anti-debugging tricks too.

That being said, to answer your question - no, IsDebuggerPresent is not secure. It's not meant to be, because it's purpose is not to prevent debugging, it's purpose is to aid debugging. i.e. for release-mode software to output debug strings if a debugger is present, but not to waste any execution time attempting to do so if it's not.

Answer (score 2):

Note that -as far the legislation of many countries works- until what I do remains by myself, once I have a licence to use, it is up to me to decide *how* to use. The law explicitly says that adding other condition or limitation is not legal and that licences adding those conditions are invalid.

If I have your licence and the debugger licence as well of the OS licence you have no rights in prohibiting me to analyze how your software works. And If I want to produce another software that interact with yours I have the full right to do it, until the licence I'll use in selling my product makes your product and licence prerequisites.

These tricks can be even legally asked to be removed (checking what software is running on my computer to decide if you can run or not is a violation of my privacy: I have the full right to run whatever software I'm licensed to use. In France, Italy and Germany there are already convicted sentences about similar cases: if I have your licence and your software refuse to start I have the full right to be refunded and I can also ask to refund the "moral damages" of the intrusion your software made on my system. There are companies who had been sentenced for billion euros of damage!).

Consider these possibilities as part of your "cost", and evaluate if there is or not the "business case".

Moral of the story: If you don't trust your user why should your user trust you? If the IT department of my company finds these tricks in a product, will simply drop that product from it's internal portfolio. And this is a potential business loss for you. And this is also another thing to take into account.

Comment: It really depends on the reason for the reverse engineering, and the reason for preventing it. In the EU it is legal to reverse engineer for a purposes of legitimate interoperability, but it is still illegal to reverse engineer for anything other than normal exploitation of the software. i.e. if you are trying to reverse engineer for the purposes of breaking copy protection, that is illegal. There is some pretty popular software - such as Maple Story with over 40 million users worldwide - that have anti-debugging features that are perfectly legal.

Comment: @Gerald: How can you know (and prove) why I am reversing before my action took place? It is not "illegal to reverse a copy protection". It is "illegal to redistribute the unprotected copies". That's the prosecutable effect, not the study of how the protection works. The anti-debugging features of  certain popular software are not legal. They exist since no "popular user" is interested in sustaining a legal trail for them.  There are less "popular" software that have much more interest in the business industry that cannot have such features: the company will be soon doomed off.

Comment: Incorrect. Per the EU Computer Program Directive:  "The unauthorised reproduction, translation, adaptation or transformation of the form of the code in which a copy of a computer program has been made available constitutes an infringement of the exclusive rights of the author." Reverse engineering is transformation of the code. It's only legal in limited circumstances, and even then you're not allowed to divulge any information you learned from reverse engineering to anybody else.

Comment: @Gerald: We are saying the same thing with different wording: How can you prove I'm doing a reverse engineering before I divulge any result? If I "divulge" you can claim, otherwise denying debugging is assuming an intention before any fact takes place. I's like killing someone in case one day may be a killer.